# External Windows bootable drive freezes boot screen

Tags: bootcamp, windows, usb

I installed Windows on a 128 GB USB drive to run on my 2017 MacBook Air. I boot into it by plugging in the drive, holding <kbd>Option</kbd> key and select the Windows drive. It worked really well.

Yesterday, I booted up in to Windows as usual, everything went well, and suddenly, everything froze. I got a Blue Screen Of Death saying `stopcode BUGCODE USB3 DRIVER`. And as it told me to do, I restarted my Mac.

But now, if I start up and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key the Windows drive won't appear. And if I plug it in after I hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, the entire screen freezes for about 30 seconds and then the USB is ejected again.

I am still able to use my other USB to boot up in to Linux but if I boot into macOS, it doesn't even detect the Windows Flash drive. Windows (on another pc) seems to detect it but ejects the flash drive after 10 seconds. And I really don't know what to do.

The Flash drive does the same on other Macs.

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you try formatting and reinstalling Windows on the USB drive?

Comment: forgive me if this is a stupid question, it has been a while since I worked with stuff like this. Would that not delete all my saved stuff. Also, no, I did not try that cause I can't do anything currently. If I plug in the Flash drive it won't show up anywhere. Not on my desktop, not in disk utility, and not in the choose start disk thing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The content on the drive would be deleted. Is the drive not accessible on "any" other Mac/PC? In that case, we can question the sanity of the drive.

Comment: so, it show up for a few seconds in the start up hold option key screen, then everything freezes and than it disappears. It shows up in windows (used somebody else computer) it shows up in my cali linux, but I can't acces the files their. and it does not show up in my Mac or the other Mac I was able to test it on. Also, what does that mean again? the sanity of the drive?

Comment: I mean the drive may be damaged. Did you encrypt the drive when installing Windows? That may explain why you are not able to access the files on other computer.

Comment: No, I did not encrypt it. But I think the reason that I cannot acces the files in my Kali-Linux is just because the Kali-linux and Mac or windows default files are different. I read something like that online. But no, the files are not encrypted. Cause before this all happend I was always able to acces the files while in Mac, even on other computers.

Comment: also, thank you for your help in looking for a solution @nimesh Neema

Comment: Have you updated your Windows drivers?

Comment: hmmmmm, I don't know. I don't think I did while I was still able to boot up windows. And I am not able to do so now.

Answer (score 1):

1. After the BSOD your mac should restart to "Start Windows Normally" screen hit Enter To Start Windows Normally
2. Go to device manager (Press Start and type devmgmt.msc and hit enter) and uninstall "unknown device" under "Universal Serial Bus Controllers" Tick "Delete the Driver Software for this device."
3. Now go to your Bootcamp folder i.e. BOOTCAMP_5.1.5621 or BOOTCAMP_5.1.5640 and go to Bootcamp > Drivers > Intel
4. Now run the file IntelxHCISetup.exe. It will show you the intel usb3.0 setup assistant. do not install or cancel the setup as it will delete the temporary folder in temp
5. Now go to Start and type taskmgr.exe and hit enter. It will open up Task Manager.
6. In that you have to select Intel Installation Framework and type Shift + fn + f10 to open right click menu (Right click may not work  unless you finish installing bootcamp fully).
7. Select "Go To Process", and again press the Shift + fn + f10 key combination to bring up the right click menu
8. And then select Open File Location, Now copy the contents of the folder to a new location i.e. by creating a new folder in the desktop or any other location
9. After copying the contents of the folder to a new location go to Device manager and right click the Unknown Device and press the Right click key combination Shift + fn + f10 and select Update Driver Software > Browse my computer for driver software and browse for the folder that you created in Step 8 and click next. It will detect the driver and installs it automatically.

That should solve your problem with the USB Drive.

Comment: so, it never restarted back in to windows. I am also unable to restart in to windows right now. So unfortunately I am unable to do so. I am unable to start my Mac back in to windows

Comment: Do you have a backup of your Windows files?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not.

Comment: Then you'll have to re do Boot Camp on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem booting Windows 10 created by WinToUSB to run Windows on my MacBook Air. After I selected to create a MBR Partition on the USB drive instead of GPT, the installation went fine and so far I'm running it with no problem.